# ellipse shape disappears from the background at the second opening of the app xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, ellipse

now this might be a weird question but this is the thing. i want the background of my app to be colorful and giving kids vibes so i made something like this:

[image]

using the following code where the circles in the background are ellipse shapes.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="0">

      <Ellipse Stroke="transparent"
               StrokeThickness="4"
               WidthRequest="50"
               HeightRequest="50"
               HorizontalOptions="Start" 
               Margin="10,10,0,0">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow"
                          Offset="0.2" />
            <GradientStop Color="#1cac78"
                          Offset="1.0" />
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
      </Ellipse>

      <Ellipse Stroke="transparent"
               StrokeThickness="4"
               WidthRequest="50"
               HeightRequest="50"
               HorizontalOptions="Start" 
               Margin="20,50,0,0">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow"
                          Offset="0.2" />
            <GradientStop Color="White"
                          Offset="1.0" />
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
      </Ellipse>

      <Ellipse Stroke="transparent"
               StrokeThickness="4"
               WidthRequest="50"
               HeightRequest="50"
               HorizontalOptions="End" 
               Margin="0,20,20,0">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow"
                          Offset="0.2" />
            <GradientStop Color="White"
                          Offset="1.0" />
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
      </Ellipse>

      <Ellipse Stroke="transparent"
               StrokeThickness="4"
               WidthRequest="50"
               HeightRequest="50"
               HorizontalOptions="Start" 
               Margin="30,40">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow"
                          Offset="0.2" />
            <GradientStop Color="Pink"
                          Offset="1.0" />
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
      </Ellipse>

      <Ellipse Stroke="transparent"
               StrokeThickness="4"
               WidthRequest="90"
               HeightRequest="90"
               HorizontalOptions="End" 
               Margin="10,20">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow"
                          Offset="0.2" />
            <GradientStop Color="SeaGreen"
                          Offset="1.0" />
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
      </Ellipse>

      <Ellipse Stroke="transparent"
               StrokeThickness="4"
               WidthRequest="150"
               HeightRequest="150"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               Margin="40,60">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow"
                          Offset="0.2" />
            <GradientStop Color="Pink"
                          Offset="1.0" />
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
      </Ellipse>

      <Ellipse Stroke="transparent"
               StrokeThickness="4"
               WidthRequest="50"
               HeightRequest="50"
               HorizontalOptions="End" 
               Margin="0,0,200,0">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow"
                          Offset="0.2" />
            <GradientStop Color="White"
                          Offset="1.0" />
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
      </Ellipse>

      <Ellipse Stroke="transparent"
               StrokeThickness="4"
               WidthRequest="200"
               HeightRequest="200"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
               Margin="0,-200,-60,0">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow"
                          Offset="0.2" />
            <GradientStop Color="#1cac78"
                          Offset="1.0" />
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
      </Ellipse>

    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
      <Frame Margin="20,80,20,0" 
             BorderColor="Transparent"
             CornerRadius="50"
             HeightRequest="200"
             WidthRequest="240"
             IsClippedToBounds="True"
             HorizontalOptions="Center"
             VerticalOptions="Center">

        <Image x:Name="loginback"  Aspect="AspectFill"
               Margin="-30"
               HeightRequest="220"
               WidthRequest="220" />
      </Frame>

      <Frame CornerRadius="30"  Padding="0" HeightRequest="60" Margin="40" BackgroundColor="#fafafa">
        <Entry Placeholder="Username" Margin="20,0,20,0" />
      </Frame>
      <Frame CornerRadius="30" Padding="0" HeightRequest="60" Margin="40,-20,40,0" BackgroundColor="#fafafa">
        <Entry Placeholder="Password" Margin="20,10,20,0"/>
      </Frame>

      <Button CornerRadius="20" Text="Login" FontSize="Medium"  BorderColor="#fafafa" BorderWidth="2" TextColor="White" Margin="100,20,100,0"  x:Name="login"  >
        <Button.Background>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="Green"
                          Offset="0.2" />
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow"
                          Offset="1.0" />
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
      </Button>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="30">
        <Switch  HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="50" OnColor="White" ThumbColor="Black" x:Name="rememberme" IsToggled="True"/>
        <Label Text="Remember Me" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10"/>

      </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

  </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

the problem is that at the first launch of the app, the login page appear as in the picture, but when i press back and reopen the app, the ellipses disappear and there is only a white background. why is this happening? what did i do wrong? note that this happens on my android physical device but on my ipad it seems to be working noramally. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue. It worked fine on iOS but failed on Andriod.  You could raise a Issue in Github.

As an alternative, you might try using **Skiasharp**. For more information, you could refer to [Drawing a Simple Circle in SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/circle) and [SkiaSharp shaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/effects/shaders/).